# Delete matrix columns not containing 2 or more instances of numbers between a specific range - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

If i've got a matrix which is something like:

```
400     450     450     300
450     300     450     340
450     200     300     210
300     100     300     200
200     200     100     100
475     300     225     300
```

What is the best way to delete all columns which do not contain numbers between a specific range - for example 400-500 - at least twice or more. In this example, columns B and D will be removed as B contains a number in this range only once and D contains nothing within this range.

The desired output would be:

```
400     450 
450     450
450     300
300     300
200     100
475     225
```

I've tried to use an IF statement to scan each column and move matches into a new matrix but this seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `A` to be the input matrix, you can use this matrix indexing approach -

```
A(:,sum(A>=400 & A<=450,1)>=2)
```

This must be a pretty efficient approach to your problem.

`sum(A>=400 & A<=450,1)>=2` gets us a logical array of columns that satisfy our needs and then we index into the columns of `A` with it.

Note: If the number of columns to be removed is a very small number as compared to the total number of columns, you can directly remove them instead of indexing into the matched columns for a more efficient approach in that special situation. So, in that case you can do this -

```
A(:,sum(A>=400 & A<=450,1)<2)=[];
```